# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \sin(1-x) dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate $\int_0^1 \sin(1-x) dx$. Here is my try

Let $y=1-x$, then $dy=-dx$ and we have

for $x=0,\, y=1$

for $x=1,\, y=0$

so that

\begin{split}
\int_0^1 \sin(1-x) dx &=-\int_1^0 \sin (y) dy\\
&=\cos(y)\bigg|_{y=1}^0\\
&=\cos(0)-cos(1)\\
&=1-\cos(1)\\
&=1.523 \times 10^{-4}
\end{split}

I gain the last part (i.e. $1-\cos(1)=1.523 \times 10^{-4}$) using calculator. However, when I compute $\int_0^1 \sin(1-x) dx$ using scientific calculator, it gives $8.7264 \times 10^{-3}$ as the answer. What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your calculator using degrees or radians?

Comment: The "1" in the integration limit and in the integrand $ \ \sin(1-x) \ $ is 1 _radian_.  Degrees are not used as units for the arguments of trigonometric functions in mathematical expressions, unless angles are _specifically_ defined that way (and in those cases, the expressions would include conversion factors). Your result for the definite integral is correct, but its decimal value is _considerably_ larger.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I see that indeed it is the radians-degrees that gives different answers in my calculator.